# Combobox link to MySQL and Jtextfield

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jcombobox

I have linked the `combobox` to MySQL database so that it's showing the list of employees by their names and surnames. 
The problem is that when I click on an employee I want to show his registration number in a separate `Textfield`.
I tried with this code but it doesn't work, unfortunately:

```
public void popcombo(){

    try {
        String sql ="Select registration,surname,name  from employee";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String surname = rs.getString("surname");
            String registration = rs.getString("registration");
            String name =rs.getString("name");
            StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
            st.append(surname).append("  ").append(name); 

            AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(empcombo);


            empcombo.addItem(st);

        }
    } catch(Exception ty)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ty);
    }
}


private void empcomboItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          
    String  p= empcombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try{

        String sql ="Select surname,name,registration from employee where registration='"+p+"'";


        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){

            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("registration"));
        }  
    }catch(Exception tz)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,tz);
    }  
}
```

Comment: doesn't work? means and `empcomboItemStateChanged()`?

Comment: `st.append(surname).append("  ").append(name);` you are not adding registration here,next your `where` clause?

Comment: @Satya   the combobox  only shows the names and surnames of the employees as a concatenation of two strings, i want the registration to be displayed in the textfield when i click on an employee, with this code i got the list of all employees in the combobox but when i click on an employee nothing is diplayed inside the textfield :/

Comment: `where registration='"+p+"'";`? wrong

Answer (score 0):

`empcomboItemStateChanged()`, not calling `ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);` in second method and `where registration='"+p+"'";` are wrong.
In first method, there is no need of column `registration`

```
    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        {//Now we will get only selected item
            String selectedValue = comboBox.getSelectedValue().toString();
            String values[]=selectedValue.split("\\s+");
            String sql ="Select registration from employee where surname='"+values[0]+"' and name='"+values[1]+"'";
            //since st.append(surname).append("  ").append(name);, double space between surname and name
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
            rs=ps.executeQuery();              
            if(rs.next()){
                jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("registration"));
            } 
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: this code returns ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception !  i think the split method is causing some trouble :/

Comment: are you using double or single space here `st.append(surname).append("  ").append(name);` @Sam

Comment: i'm using double space

Comment: use `Sys` statemnt for `selectedValue`. see whats the output @Sam

Comment: i'm using *getSelectedItem().tostring()* instead of getselectedvalue @Satya

Comment: use print statement n see the output

Comment: use can use `getSelectedItem().tostring()`. first see the output. @Sam

Comment: the print statement returns the registration but there is always arrayindexoutofbound, after i close the error windows i get the registration in the textfield but i want to get rid of those errors windows

Comment: where you getting `arrayindexoutofbound` exception @Sam

Comment: arrayindexoutofbound :0  and arrayindexoutofbound ; 1  , i think there is a problem with the split

Comment: whats the value of `Sysout(comboBox.getSelectedValue().toString())` @Sam

Comment: it returns the name and surname of the selected employee two times

Comment: with double space or single space. paste here@Sam

Comment: with split method are you using double or single space

Comment: then its correct. use single space in both the spaces @Sam

Comment: even with single space the error is persisting :/  i spent the whole night trying to get this code working properly  but i'm still in trouble :/

Comment: what is `:/`. paste that line here. where you are getting that exception

Answer (score 0):

i used this code:

```
   private void empcomboItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          
 try{
    {
        String selectedItem = empcombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sql ="Select registration from employee where surname='"+selectedItem.split(" ")[0]+"' and name='"+selectedItem.split(" ")[1]+"'";

        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        rs=ps.executeQuery();              
        if(rs.next()){
            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("registration"));

        } 
    }
}catch(Exception gh){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gh);
}
}
```

Comment: still getting 'arrayindexoutof..' exception

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer and special thanks  to you Satya for helping me. this is the final code :

```
  private void empcomboItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          


    try{
     String selectedItem = empcombo.getSelectedItem().toString();   
    String[] items = selectedItem.split(" ");
    if(items.length >= 2){


        String sql ="Select matricule from employés where nom='"+items[0]+"' and prénom='"+items[1]+"'";

        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        rs=ps.executeQuery();              
        if(rs.next()){
            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString("matricule"));

        } }

}catch(Exception gh){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gh);
}
}
```